# Reset itertools.count

Tags: python, python-itertools

I want to reset the count when a condition happens. I tried to do the following but didn't work!

```
c = itertools.count(1)
for i in range(100):
    next(c)
    print(c)
    if next(c) == 10:
    c = itertools.count(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use what `next` returns for comparison, not instance of `itertools.count` itself:

```
import itertools
c = itertools.count(1)
for i in range(100):
    value = next(c)
    print(c)
    if value == 10:
        c = itertools.count(1)
```

Note that following code do not reset existing `itertools.count` instance, but rather put brand new instance of `itertools.count` under `c` when condition is met.